# how put empty line in json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i try to do a python's scraping script who takes informations and put it in a json file,

but the problem is i don't know how go to a newline after my information.
MY json file is:

```
Test1:blablablablaTest2:Blablabal:Test3BLABLABLA etc...
```

and i want

```
Test1:blablabl
test2:blablabla
etc
```

there is my code:
(i tried to put '\n' but it writes \n at the end of the line)

```
with open(source, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   json.dump(date_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
   json.dump(numeroFacture_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
   json.dump(montantTotal_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
   json.dump(tva_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
   json.dump(montantHt_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add `f.write("\n")` after each `json.dump`?

Comment: oh it works! i tried to put the \n in the string, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, just add `f.write("\n")` after each `json.dump` sentence, so like this:

```py
with open(source, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(date_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    f.write("\n")
    json.dump(numeroFacture_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    f.write("\n")
    json.dump(montantTotal_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    f.write("\n")
    json.dump(tva_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    f.write("\n")
    json.dump(montantHt_json, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```